# drag & rotate individual items

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, rotatetransform

i have spent an entire day trying to figure this out but, to no avail.  i have several draggable pieces of texts on a page.  these pieces of texts are also supposed to have the ability to be rotated.  well, the draggable part is fine.  the rotate is even working.  however, it is not working for individual items - whenever i rotate 1 item, anything else w/the rotate code in it, rotates as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are applying `style="-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);"` to the class

```
cc-element ui-draggable cc-active'
```

That's why both element rotate. So apply style to the id rather than apply to the class.

You can have a look [here](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html)

Comment: the div id? if so, which one? i looked at your link and still came away confused.  would you mind showing me how you would change the code and what that would look like?

Comment: I'm still confused. can you please help, please? i need to get this solved. thanks.